# How do I write a custom DataGridView in C# with a master-detail layout?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

Please excuse me if this question has already been asked. However, I couldn't find anything suitable for my search on the internet.

My real question: How can I develop a DataGridView with a master-detail layout in C#? I want to write a custom control that enhances DataGridView so that you can optionally use a master-detail layout. The detail should be a subordinate DataGridView. The DGV should allow all possible data sources. This means that you should be able to query data from a database with the classes from the System.Data.Sql namespace and insert it into the grid. You should also be able to integrate data with the Entity Framework into the master-detail layout, as well as manual data entry. For the latter I have included sample code below.

```
// generated by WinForms Designer
DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();

// I always have this method, since I once had problems
// with auto-generated stuff
private void GenerateGridColumns()
{
    // Example: Dinosaurs

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colId = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    colId.Name = "colId";
    colId.ReadOnly = true;
    colId.Visible = false;
    grid.Columns.Add(colId);

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colName = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    colName.Name = "colName";
    colName.HeaderText = "Name";
    colName.ReadOnly = true;
    grid.Columns.Add(colName);

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colPeriod = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    colPeriod.Name = "colPeriod";
    colPeriod.HeaderText = "Period";
    colPeriod.ReadOnly = true;
    grid.Columns.Add(colPeriod);
}

// fill DGV with sample data
private void FillGrid()
{
    object[] values = { 0, "Tyrannosaurus rex", "Cretateous" };
    grid.Rows.Add(values);

    values[0] = 1;
    values[1] = "Compsognathus";
    values[2] = "Jurassic";
    grid.Rows.Add(values);

    values[0] = 2;
    values[1] = "Allosaurus";
    grid.Rows.Add(values);
}
```

Thanks for your support. If I ever release the DLL of this control, then I will appreciate those of you who can help me.

Comment: Microsoft have pretty nice docs now: [Walkthrough: Creating a Master/Detail Form Using Two Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/creating-a-master-detail-form-using-two-datagridviews)

Comment: @Fabio: I tried this code, but it's not exactly, what I want to do. What I want to do, is a DataGridView with a DataGridView in it. So everytime when I click on a + symbol in the master grid, I want to show a second DGV with Data depending on that master.

Comment: I haven't tested Fabio's suggestion, but if it didn't work for you then you could try [this VB version on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/835501/Master-Detail-Datagridview), but it either needs converting (see comments section) or dll referencing. (Also noteworthy, it has some resizing issues.) Conversely, you could also look into Telerik's RadGridView which I've had no issues with, but that costs money.